# I cannot get my map to print is value outside of the function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I am trying to access the values of the map outside of the function getbetlist like do a console.log(bettingPool) outside of that function but whenever I do that it just prints {}.  However inside the function getbetlist it prints the correct output.

I have tried changing the varible types, setting the var, creating a new var and resetting it and nothing has worked thus far.

```
var db = firebase.firestore();
var bettingPool = {}
var marketSplit = {}
var weightedMarketSplit = {}
var msToNextDay = 0;
var test;

async function startNewGame() {
await getBetList();
var now = new Date();

var nextDay = new Date(
    now.getFullYear(),
    now.getMonth(),
    now.getDate() + 1,
    7, 59, 59
);
test();
msToNextDay = nextDay.getTime() - now.getTime();
// console.log(msToNextDay)
// bettingPool = {}
// marketSplit = {}
// weightedMarketSplit = {}
// setTimeout(startNewGame(), msToNextDay);
}
startNewGame();



async function getBetList() {
console.log("inside getBetList")
const users = []
const accuracy = []
db.collection('Bets').get().then(
    function (querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(
            function (doc) {
                doc.data().userDoc.onSnapshot(docSnapshot => {

                    /* Betting Pool Split
                            bettingPool - By Money
                            marketSplit - By Users
                            weightedMarketSplit - By users * accuracy
                    */
                    if (!bettingPool[doc.data()['stockId']]) {
                        bettingPool[doc.data()['stockId']] = {}
                        marketSplit[doc.data()['stockId']] = {}
                        weightedMarketSplit[doc.data()['stockId']] = {}
                    }
                    if (doc.data()['direction'] == 'Up') {
                        if (!bettingPool[doc.data()['stockId']].Up) {
                            bettingPool[doc.data()['stockId']].Up = 0.0
                            marketSplit[doc.data()['stockId']].Up = 0
                            weightedMarketSplit[doc.data()['stockId']].Up = 0.0
                        }
                        marketSplit[doc.data()['stockId']].Up += 1
                        bettingPool[doc.data()['stockId']].Up += Number(doc.data()['bet'])
                        weightedMarketSplit[doc.data()['stockId']].Up += (docSnapshot.data()['accuracy'])
                    }
                    else if (doc.data()['direction'] == 'Down') {
                        if (!bettingPool[doc.data()['stockId']].Down) {
                            bettingPool[doc.data()['stockId']].Down = 0.0
                            marketSplit[doc.data()['stockId']].Down = 0
                            weightedMarketSplit[doc.data()['stockId']].Down = 0.0
                        }
                        marketSplit[doc.data()['stockId']].Down += 1
                        bettingPool[doc.data()['stockId']].Down += Number(doc.data()['bet'])
                        weightedMarketSplit[doc.data()['stockId']].Down += (docSnapshot.data()['accuracy'])
                    }
                    test = bettingPool;
                })
            }
        )
    }
)

// for (var user of users) {
//     db.collection("Users").doc('' + user).onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
//         // if(querySnapshot.data()['accuracy']) {
//         //     accuracy.push(querySnapshot.data()['accuracy'])
//         // }
//         // else {
//         //     accuracy.push(0.5);
//         // }
//         // console.log(querySnapshot.data())
//     })
// }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of funky code to modify a global object inside a function, for multiple reasons. Especially because the function is called "getBetList" but it doesnt get anything, it just updates a variable somewhere else. Its much cleaner to do something like

```
const bettingPool = await getBetList()
```

And have getBetList return the betList.

This should also fix your problem.